# Find the index of the next value greater than threshold in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I've got an array `a`,

```
a = np.array([50,49,47,55,68,70,65])
```

And I want the index of the first value that is greater than 65 (i.e.`4`). What is the fastest way I can do this task in Numpy (since my actual dataset is much larger)?

Comment: So, `(a > 65).argmax()`?

Comment: @coldspeed What is the time complexity?

Comment: Linear? Your array isn't sorted, you can't hope for anything much better.

Comment: @coldspeed Why close? He wanted best performance and time complexity, it's different case. Plus you can use at most N operations, not at least N as is the case with `argmax`.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I did not close it? Why did you ping me?

Comment: @coldspeed my bad, indeed, mobile is not helpful, apologies.

Comment: You meant to ping @Divakar (btw, you can edit your comment upto 5 minutes, and you can change the user you ping).

Answer (score 0):

argmax will find the index of first True,
try this `np.argmax(a>65)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) and it's decorators. Thanks to this library you can achieve better performance scores than numpy (or on par) while using plain Python.

In your case it could be:

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def find_greater(array, threshold: int):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] > threshold:
            return i
```

This option is better in terms of time complexity, maximum `O(n)` (usually much less) than approaches like the one suggested in comments.